# What is the maximum reviewer score for IEEE conference papers?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, ieee

I am wondering if conferences supported by IEEE follow the same score scale. I could not figure out if there is a scale from 1 to 10 or from 1 to 5.

Answer (score 4):

IEEE conferences are allowed to organize their own reviewing system, so there is no uniform system between them.